# What is the best way to perform `sum_by_sql`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 2.3.8 there is a class method `ActiveRecord::Base.count_by_sql` which allows to perform custom `SELECT count(*) ...`. Is it save to execute customized `SELECT sum(...) ...` query with this method? If not, what should be done to execute such a query? Is `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` the only option?

Thanks.

EDIT: Query I want to perform has another query nested. That's why I believe methods from `ActiveRecord::Calculations` are not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select_value` from `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::DatabaseStatements` module is the answer. It returns the value present in the first column of the first row returned by query. `select_value` returns `String`, so conversion may be necessary.

Example:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_value("Some complicated sql")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `ActiveRecord::Calculations`. The API docs are [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html).

You can do something like this (assuming you have `User` model):

```
User.maximum(:updated_at)
# Generates:
# SELECT max(`users`.updated_at) AS max_updated_at FROM `users`
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it is not enough in my case. I haven't mention that clear enough before, but I need to pass raw SQL (at least I think so). My query has another query nested, it looks like this: `SELECT MAX(...) FROM (here goes nested query I can't get rid of)`. That's why I need a method like `count_by_sql`.